# how to install sdk and adt in eclipse i have installed https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but i still cant open SDK manager(no sdk manager)

Tags: android

how can I install SDK properly ive tried this but failed

Enter "Android Development Tools Plug-in" for the "Name." Enter "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" for the "Location." This tells Eclipse what plug-in you are trying to install and where to download it from.

Click "OK." Although "https" is more secure, if you have trouble acquiring the plug-in, you can replace "https" with "http" in the "Location" URL.

Tick the check box you see next to "Developer Tools" in the "Available Software" window that appears. Click "Next" to see the list of tools that will be downloaded.

Accept the license agreement and click "Finish" to complete the installation. If a security warning telling you that "You are installing software that contains unsigned content" appears, you can safely click "OK."

Restart Eclipse and configure the ADT plug-in to find the Android SDK tools. Click on "Window," select "Preferences," select "Android" in the left panel and click "Browse" for the "SDK Location." Navigate to the Android SDK folder, click "Apply" and then "OK."

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can I install sdk properly coz I tried the above approach but it didn't work I can access sdk manager

Comment: have you tried http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html step by step from this link.  Then check http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

Comment: the instructions are the same but I will try to run it again one more time

Comment: problem is after this step
5.In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
I cant proced coz next/finish button is not clickable maybe because ive don't it before but I cant access SDK manager what could be missing in my installation

Comment: Did you set SDK location in Preferences->Android?

Comment: I did but nothing happened. Actually it was already set when I clicked it.i cant find the sdk manager.

Comment: found it thanks for your help I just didn't show the icons need to show it on window customize perspective